# AngularJS how to share ng-model value to different view

Tags: angularjs

I'm stumped on how I can pass share the value of ng-model to a different view. For example, I have a application with a sidebar. In the sidebar the user can select o color using ng-Bootstrap colorPicker. So the user can choose what color they want the text to be on there page when they have configured it.

Here is a snapshot of what I am trying to explain:
[image: what I am trying to explain]

The controller for side nav html is:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="headerBigColor" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Header</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right input-group">
                    <input style="background: {{headerBigColor}}; color: {{headerBigColor}};" colorpicker  colorpicker-position="right" class="span2" type="text" id="headerBigColor" ng-model="headerBigColor" required="required" />
                    <small class="help-block" ng-show="headerBigColor">HEX Value:<br />{{headerBigColor}}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the html for the view I want to share ng-model"headerBigColor" is

```
            <div class="brand-program-txt">
                <h1 style="color: {{headerBigColor}} !important;">Organization</h1>
                <hr/>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="pull-left">Program Title</span><span class="pull-right">Program Track </span><span class="pull-right"> Deadline Date</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use $rootScope for application wide variables or a service/factory to hold these. I suggest $rootScope. Bind colorpicker to $rootScope.headerBigColor instread of $scope.headerBigColor. It will be visible to all. Don't forget to inject $rootScope in other controllers.

Comment: Similiar to using $rootScope would be to have a parent controller from which child controllers would be able to access the same piece of data. Be sure to 'dot -> uiModel.headerBigColor' the data so you dont experience scope issues with prototypical inheritance in your children.

Answer (score 1):

This is something of an application design question. The way I have solved this problem is to create an "ambient state service" in AngularJS that I use to store values that are shared between views.

The service has an interface similar to the following:

```
value getValue(key)
void setValue(key, value)
```

Inject this service into the controllers of both views, and have the sidebar controller set the value. Make sure that the "main" controller gets the value from the service on every digest cycle (using a $scope $watch on the state service getValue function).

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a controller for the side nav and preview window respectively.

Both controllers can then interact with a shared service which will store the color data.

Side Nav controller:

```
.controller('SideNav', ['$scope', 'ColorService', function($scope, ColorService) {
  $scope.setSelectedColor = ColorService.setSelectedColor;
});
```

Preview Window controller:

```
.controller('PreviewWindow', ['$scope', 'ColorService', function($scope, ColorService) {
  $scope.color = null;

  $scope.$watch(ColorService.getSelectedColor, function(color) {
    $scope.color = color;
  });
});
```

Shared Color Service:

```
.factory('ColorService', function() {
  var selectedColor = null;
  var service = {};

  service.setSelectedColor = function(color) {
    selectedColor = color;
  };

  service.getSelectedColor = function() {
    return selectedColor;
  };

  return service;
});
```

Comment: Apologies @John Bledsoe - realised after posting I have inadvertently expanded on your answer. Hopefully it's still of use to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I achieved this.

SIDEBAR Controller

```
configAppControllers.controller('BrandingCtrl', ["$scope", "$location", "httprequesthandle", "$stateParams", "handlelocalstorage", "$modal", "tickmark", "$rootScope",
function ($scope, $location, httprequesthandle, $stateParams, handlelocalstorage, $modal, tickmark, $rootScope) {
    $scope.headerImage = "images/brand_img.jpg";
    $scope.hasImage = true;
    // end Branding Color service
    $rootScope.$on('changedHeader', function (event, color) {
        if (color !== undefined) {
            $scope.backgroundcolor = color;
            $scope.hasImage = false;
        }
    });

    $rootScope.$on('changedHeadLine', function (event, color) {
        $scope.headlineColor = color;
    });


    $rootScope.$on('changedBackgroundImage', function (event, srccode) {
        $scope.headerImage = srccode;
        $scope.hasImage = true;
    });

}]);
```

MAINPAGE View Controller

```
configAppControllers.controller('BrandingSidebarCtrl', ['$scope', 'httprequesthandle', '$stateParams', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
function ($scope, httprequesthandle, $stateParams, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    var sideBar;

    $scope.$watch("headerBigColor", function (color) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('changedHeader', $scope.headerBigColor);
    });

    $scope.$watch("headLineTxt", function (color) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('changedHeadLine', $scope.headLineTxt);
    });

    $scope.$watch("headLineTxt2", function (color) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('changedHeadLine', $scope.headLineTxt2);
    });
```

HTML On mainPage View

```
<div class="brand-img" style="background-color:{{backgroundcolor}} !important;">
        <img src="{{headerImage}}" ng-show="hasImage" alt="Branding" />
        <div class="brand-program-txt">
            <h1 style="color: {{headlineColor}} !important;">Organization</h1>
            <hr/>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <span class="pull-left">Program Title</span><span class="pull-right">Program Track </span><span class="pull-right"> Deadline Date</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

HTML on sidebar

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="headerBigColor" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Header</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right input-group">
                    <input style="background: {{headerBigColor}}; color: {{headerBigColor}};" colorpicker colorpicker-position="right" class="span2" type="text" id="headerBigColor" ng-model="headerBigColor" required="required" />
                    <small class="help-block" ng-show="headerBigColor">HEX Value:<br />{{headerBigColor}}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="headLineTxt" class="col-sm-7 control-label">Headline Text</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5 pull-right">
                    <input style="background: {{headLineTxt}}; color: {{headLineTxt}};" colorpicker colorpicker-position="right" class="span2" type="text" id="headLineTxt" ng-model="headLineTxt" required="required" />
                    <small class="help-block" ng-show="headLineTxt">HEX Value: {{headLineTxt}}</small>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The $rootScope approach obviously works - but I've found it painful to manage the number of events (essentially magic strings) in growing applications (you already have three). I would consider $rootScope appropriate for genuine application wide concerns, e.g. error handling, application exit. As always "it depends" :)